# Rails Geocoder - Still learning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure it's a simply issue due to me not fully understanding how bits fit together in Rails...

I've followed the [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) but I'm having trouble implementing it into my app (I've had it working stand-alone).

The error I get is

> undefined method `nearbys'

Here's what I've got:
user.rb

```
  geocoded_by :full_address   
  after_validation :geocode

  def full_address
    [address1, address2, address3, city, country, postcode].compact.join(', ')   
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def index
    @title = "All users"

    if params[:search].present?
      @users = User.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h3>Nearby locations</h3>
<ul>
<% for user in @users.nearbys(10) %>
  <li><%= link_to user.address1, user %> (<%= user.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

_sidebar.html.erb

```
            <%= form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>
                <p>
                <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
                <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
                </p>
            <% end %>
```

Thanks

If I comment out the .nearbys

```
<% for user in @users#.nearbys(10) %>
  <li><%= link_to user.latitude, user %> (<%= user.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
<% end %>
```

The search works. Could this be a problem with the install of geocoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `nearbys` is a function on your model, not on a collection of models. The variable `@users` contains a collection of `User` models. You need to call the function on a single model instance, for example for each user in `@users`.

As an example, but not sure if you really want this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% user.nearbys(10).each do |near_user| %>
    <li><%= link_to near_user.latitude, near_user %> (<%= near_user.distance.round(2) %> miles)</li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

(Note that I also changed the `for user in @users` to use `@users.each do |user|`, which is more "*Rubyish*".)

Comment: I understand that this is an old answer - but thank you for it and I've used it in my app in user's show page - i.e. when someone visit's user's profile, it shows nearby users before the profile, NOW...how can I modify it so that currently viewed user is not part of that list.

Thank you in advance.