# Rails geocoder near

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I want to return a list of job postings that are near a location (based on [latitude, longitude]). I am using [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and it seems to be working. I can import a CSV file with a list of addresses and `geocoder` populates the latitude and the longitude columns.

But I can't seem to get the `near` or `nearby` functions to work. It returns a `undefined method` error. I've tried following this: [Rails Geocoder - Still learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620235/rails-geocoder-still-learning) which explains that nearby is a model function. But the example there did not work for me either.

This is what I have in my show.html.erb:

```
<%= @jobposting.latitude %>, <%= @jobposting.longitude %>
```

40.7494011, -73.9389437

```
<% @location = Jobposting.near([@jobposting.latitude, @jobposting.longitude], 150) %>
<%= @location.inspect %>
```

It does not error but returns a empty array: `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` when there are points within 10 miles of the latitude and longitude.

I'm unsure if I am calling it incorrectly, based on the documentation it looks like `near` is used with the model but not limited to calling it in the model.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, I believe the method is `nearbys`, not `nearby`. That might explain the undefined method error you mentioned. I don't know why you aren't getting results for the `near` function. The code you posted for the `near` method looks okay to me.